# Comparing the following special character in JavaScript is returning inappropriate result?

Tags: javascript

There is a case when I receive a string with the following special characters in it:

```
<!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?></.,';][=-`~DS0>
```

While performing a compare operation on this string using the double equal to (==) operator in JavaScript it is not yielding the appropriate result.

Although both the strings contain the same specified string the compare operation does not return true.

My case would translate somewhat like this in JavaScript:

```
var strValue = "<!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?></.,';][=-`~DS0>";
var itrValue = "<!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?></.,';][=-`~DS0>";
if (itrValue == strValue) {
    alert("True");
} else {
    alert("false");
}
```

Comment: You have an unescaped double quote in the middle of itrValue. This gives an error "SyntaxError: invalid label" in Firebug. Does it really alert "false", or does it just cease quietly and painfully?

Comment: No it doesnt return anything. Actually i want the code to function that way. return me true or false.I need to modify the strings in such a way that comparision on them can be performed.

And yes the problem is due to 2 things
1)as u specified unescaped double quote
2)the presence of HTML Character Entities refer to http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp



Is there a way to compare such kinda strings in javascript ?

Answer (score 3):

It only returns true if and only if the strings are identical.  You can use indexof if you want to determine if a string is inside of another one: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#indexof

Answer (score 2):

First: I think you need to escape those quotation marks with backslashes (something like \").

Second: as far as I can see those two strings are not identical. You might want to try something more like [indexof](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_IndexOf.asp) (W3 schools reference), as popester states correctly.

Comment: actually the strings are equivalent . but somehow the editor doesnt display it appropriately. both the strings are <!@#$%^&*()_+|}{":?></.,';][=-~DS0>

Comment: You need to escape the '"' (and possibly any "'" as well), the stackoverflow editor actually points out your problem (look at the different colors in your code block)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `indexOf` method which will return `-1` if an index cannot be found as the two answers above state.

Something slightly different (not entirely sure if you're looking for this, `indexOf` is probably your best bet) is using the `String.match` or `String.split` method. `String.match` will return `null` if there is no match, otherwise it will return an array of all elements containing your string (EG:

```
var str = "Test123 ABC Test 123Test ABC"
var macthes = str.match("/Test/g") // You can have any regular expression here
document.write(matches[0])
document.write(matches[1])
document.write(matches[2])
```

Will produce Test123 Test 123Test
`String.split` will produce an array of strings split at your initial string.

Answer (score 0):

I just escaped the double quote in the string and I got a nice `true` from the `==` operator...

```
var strValue = "<!@#$%^&*()_+|}{\":?></.,';][=-`~DS0>";
var itrValue = "<!@#$%^&*()_+|}{\":?></.,';][=-`~DS0>";
alert(strValue == itrValue)
```